# Generated table cells from json object do not align accordingly in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a json file where i grab the objects from a list. The list of objects look like this:

```
"data": [
            {
              "title": "Subscription #1",
              "subtitle": "12-01-2022",
              "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.",
              "link": "subscription-1"
            },
            {
              "title": "Subscription #2",
              "subtitle": "19-01-2022",
              "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.",
              "link": "subscription-2"
            },
            {
              "title": "Subscription #3",
              "subtitle": "04-02-2022",
              "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.",
              "link": "subscription-3"
            },
            {
              "title": "Subscription #4",
              "subtitle": "Expired",
              "description": "Lorem ipsum dolar set amit.",
              "link": "subscription-4"
            }
          ]
```

I also have a view where i show the table contents based on the generated json objects:

```
Table(
    border: TableBorder.all(
        width: 1.0, color: Colors.white),
    children: [
      for (var object in widget.selectedMenuItems[index]
          ['data'])
        TableRow(children: [
          TableCell(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment:
                  MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                if (object.containsKey("title"))
                  Text(
                    object["title"].toString(),
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                else
                  Container(),
                if (object.containsKey("subtitle"))
                  Text(
                    object["subtitle"].toString(),
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                else
                  Container(),
                if (object.containsKey("description"))
                  Text(
                    object["description"].toString(),
                    style:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  )
                else
                  Container()
              ],
            ),
          )
        ])
    ]),
```

This is the output of the table:

[image]

As you can see the cells don't align accordingly. This is because i show each key value from the objects separately with if else because sometimes the keys don't exist in the object and so i don't want an empty table contents.

For example I have list with a key missing. This is the example of the table where the key subtitle is missing the object FAQ's:

[image]

I have to mention that it's a usecase for me to generate table cells separately. My question is how can I align the cells accordingly and still generate the table cells with if else?

Answer (score 0):

The table widget has some methods to restrict the size of its children (rows).

```dart
columnWidths: {
         0: FlexColumnWidth(1),
         1: FlexColumnWidth(2),
              },
```

You can also set it with fixed column width.

`defaultColumnWidth: FixedColumnWidth(100),`

Your issue stems from your rows having different sizes, that's why they are unaligned.